# cout << with char* argument prints string, not pointer value

Tags: c++

This:

```
const char * terry = "hello";
cout<<terry;
```

prints `hello` instead of the memory address of the `'h'`. Why is this happening?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does cout print char arrays differently from other arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501816/why-does-cout-print-char-arrays-differently-from-other-arrays)

Answer (score 106):

The reason for that is that `std::cout` will treat a `char *` as a pointer to (the first character of) a C-style string and print it as such. If you want the *address* instead, you can just cast it to a pointer that *isn't* treated that way, something like:

```
cout << (void *) terry;
```

(or use the `const void *` cast if you're worried about casting away constness, something that's not an issue in this particular case).

---

If you're more of a purist than pragmatist, you can also use the C++ `static_cast`, along the lines of:

```
cout << static_cast <const void *> (terry);
```

though it's unnecessary in this particular case, the cast to a `void *` will work fine. The following sample code shows all these options in action:

```
#include <iostream>
int main (void) {
    const char *terry = "hello";
    std::cout << terry << '\n';
    std::cout << (void *) terry << '\n';
    std::cout << (const void *) terry << '\n';
    std::cout << static_cast<const void *> (terry) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

outputting (the address may be different in your environment):

```
hello
0x8048870
0x8048870
0x8048870
```

Note that, when using the `static_cast`, you should ensure you don't try to cast away the constness with `static_cast <void *>` (that's what `const_cast` is for). This is one of the checks done by the newer C++ casts and the old-style cast does not have this limitation.

Comment: It doesn't treat the `char*` value as a C-style string; it treats it as a *pointer* to (the first character of) a C-style string.

Comment: @Keith, semantics problem, apologies for that. What I meant is that it prints it out as a C-style string. I'll clarify.

Comment: Is the word "semantics" meant to imply that it's an unimportant distinction? It isn't.

Comment: @Keith, no, it wasn't meant to mean unimportant (otherwise I wouldn't have changed it). I meant I didn't get my meaning across as well as I should have. Hopefully, the edits have fixed that.

Comment: Please don't use C-style cast. Dangerous, unclear, hard to spot. (For example, here you dropped constness without thinking of it.)

Comment: It's only dangerous to those who don't know what they're doing. Dropping of constness is irrelevant in this case since you're not doing anything with the pointer where that will matter. Yes, if you'd cast the pointer then gone off and used it incorrectly, I'd agree, but I expect practitioners of a language to learn hozw to use it safely. I didn't let my son start using my more dangerous tools until he'd proven he knew the issues with them :-)

Comment: I see only 2 reasons of using a C-style cast in C++: 1. cast to an inaccessible base class; 2. laziness to type a few more characters.

Comment: You talk of laziness as if it's a _bad_ thing. It's only bad if there's an actual decremental effect, otherwise it's known as efficiency. There are no problems with using old-style casts in _this particular_ situation and they're as much a part of the C++ language as any other (even stuff like cstdio is acceptable provided you understand the issues).

Comment: However, I can see I'm unlikely to convince you. The battle between purist and pragmatist seems to be rearing its head here, both sides have their points but we may as well be discussing vi vs. emacs :-) So I suggest you vote your conscience and we'll let the people decide. I'll add the newer style as an option but I still maintain it's not necessary in this case.

Comment: If pointer points to a single character variable, what should be the output of cout? In the below case, I get some C followied by 3 garbage characters: char a='C';
    char *ptr3=&a;
    cout<<"ptr = "<<ptr3<<'\n';

Comment: @Rajesh, what is *should* be could be a matter for discussion :-) What it will most likely be is basically the character followed by random output, depending on whatever arbitrary data comes *after* that character in memory. By using a `char*`, you are declaring that there is a C-style string at that location. If there actually *isn't,* then all bets are off.

Comment: @paxdiablo Can you provide a reference to any other SO post which talks about `constness` in detail? I am pretty new to `C++`.

Answer (score 29):

The `<<` operator on `std::cout` is overloaded. Its behavior depends on the type of the right operand. (It's actually several different functions, all named `operator<<`; the compiler decides which one to call.)

If you give it a `char*` or `const char*`, it treats the operand as a pointer to (the first character of) a C-style string, and prints the contents of that string:

```
const char * terry = "hello";
cout << terry; // prints "hello"
```

If you give it a `char` value, it prints that value as a character:

```
cout << *terry;   // prints "h"
cout << terry[0]; // the same
```

If you give it a pointer of type `void*`, it prints that pointer value (in some implementation-defined way, typically hexadecimal):

```
cout << static_cast<const void*>(terry); // prints something like 0x4008e4
```

Treating a `char*` or `const char*` as a pointer to a C-style string is a special case, and the only one (that I can think of) that causes `operator<<` to print something other than the value of the operand. The reason for this goes back to C++'s roots in C, which doesn't have a "string" type and manipulates strings via `char*` pointers.

There are numerous other overloads for `operator<<`, for various integer and floating-point numeric types, for `std::string`, and so forth.

Comment: Another "special" case I can think of is trying to print a function pointer, which will choose the `bool` overload (unless the function has the signature of a stream manipulator): http://ideone.com/OkutRD (admittedly, it prints the "value" of the pointer converted to `bool`, so this is "less special" than the `const char*` case)

Comment: @KeithThompson So, that means that it's the `overloaded version` of `operator<<` that makes the string get printed and not the pointer value while in case of something like `int*` the pointer value will get printed and not the value. Am I correct here?

Answer (score 13):

You should change your code to this:

```
cout << static_cast<const void*>(terry);
```

The problem is that `<<` operator is overloaded for pointers to C-style strings for printing the content of the string. If you cast it to the raw pointer instead, you will have  the default behaviour of printing pointer using iostreams as you want.

Answer (score 5):

`std::cout` is defined as `std::ostream` with [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) definition of `operator<<`.

Notably this line:

```
template< class CharT, class Traits >
basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>& operator<<( basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>& os,
                                     const char* s );
```

This gets selected when you use `<<` with an argument of type `char*`.

The case of any other non-char pointer type goes [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt):

```
basic_ostream& operator<<( const void* value );
```

This continues to [`std::num_put`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_put/put) which is made for formatting numeric values. Therefore, the pointer is interepreted numerically like `%p` in C formatting functions.

Answer (score 2):

`cout` is overloaded so that when you give it a `char*`, it will print as a pointer to a C-style string. So, it prints out the characters until it hits a null terminating character.

If you used `printf` instead of `cout`, you would see the address. You could also cast the pointer to another type, say `(void*)` and you would also get the address.

Comment: `printf` itself doesn't decide how it prints, you still have to use the correct format specifier, the same way you have to use the same type in C++. For example, `printf` with `%s` will have exactly the same issue as `cout` with a `char *`. To get the pointer, you'd use a format specifier `%p`.

Answer (score -2):

"hello" is a string, i.e. the char array. `const char*` is a pointer to this array, so when you dereference this pointer, you get the value of the first element.

It is like if you have

```
int a[] = {1, 2, 3};
int *b = a;
cout << *b << endl;
```

you get just `1` printed.

Comment: why im not getting the memory address?

Comment: @Mr.Puff If you want to get the memory address of char pointer, you should cast it to void pointer before, because `ostream <<` operator is overloaded for char pointers to print strings.