# How to get the memory address of a pointer to a char[] in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Full disclosure: This is homework. I'm just really confused about one part.
I have this code in a c++ program:

```
char * charArray = new char[100];

//fill charArray 
char c = '.';
for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
{
    charArray[i] = c;
    c = c + 1;
}
cout <<"Char Array: " << endl;
for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
{
    cout << "Type: Char @ " << &charArray[i] << " = " << charArray[i] <<endl;
}
```

At a different point in my program I have pretty much the exact same code but instead of a char array it is a float array. When I print out the float array I get Type: Float @ whatAppearsToBeAProperMemoryAddress = correctFloat#.

However although the chars are correct the address don't appear to be. The address for the char array go like this:
./0123456789<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~?????????????????? 
/0123456789<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~??????????????????

....
all the way to 
??
?

So obviously instead of getting the address I am getting varying degrees of what should be the contents of the array. I am very confused and any pointers would be appreciated. This is my first crack at c++.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17813423/cout-with-char-argument-prints-string-not-pointer-value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `&charArray[i]` is still a `char*` pointing to the ith character of the string. So it is used as a whole string. Try to cast as this:

```
(void*)&charArray[i]
```

that is the same as:

```
(void*)(charArray+i);
```

Comment: I'm going to mark your question as correct because it worked perfectly thanks. However you said &charArray[i] is still a char * pointing to the ith character of the string. I'm confused as to why if it is pointing t the ith character of the string it is printing the whole really long string? I hope that makes since and sorry if its a dumb question.

Comment: @MichelleJS it prints from the `i`th character until it finds a `\0`. This is what output streams do when they are given a `char*`: they assume it is the beginning of a null-terminated string.

Comment: @juanchopanza - Thanks. That makes tons more sense now.