# Setting pointer to an array c++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have this problem for CS. I'm using the code `p3 = &s1[3];` however when I cout `p3` it displays the value instead of the address. Is this to expected and the problem is right or is there something I am doing wrong?

> Given the following declarations:
>
> ```
> int i = 3, j, *p1 = &i, *p2;
> char s1[20] = "Wow, more pointers!", *p3;
> ```
>
> Write a statement that makes `p3` equal to the address of the fourth
>   element of `s1`.

Comment: my apologies I was typing fast I was already using the code p3 = &s1[3]; so it compiles fine the output is still the array of characters and I want it to be the address of that element alone

Comment: We don't care how fast you type, but we expect complete code that was tested before posting. We don't like to chase ghosts.

Answer (score 4):

The `<<` operator for streams has several overloads. One of them takes a `char*`, and prints a string (a sequence of chars starting from that address, until the next 0). A different one takes a `void*` (a pointer to anything), and prints the address it points to.

If you cast the pointer to `void*` yourself, it will force the compiler to choose the `void*` overload that prints the address:

```
cout << (void*)p3;
```

Your pointer assignment is not wrong; the problem is when you print it.

Answer (score 2):

That's how std::cout treats (char*). This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17813423/cout-with-char-argument-prints-string-not-pointer-value) contains comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 0):

By assigning to `*p3` you are not modifying the pointer `p3`, you are modifying the memory that it points to. To modify the pointer `p3` itself, just assign to `p3`.

Comment: The original post has no assignment to p3.

Comment: @cliffordheath: read the entire question in full

Comment: @dreamlax: The OP has no assignment to p3. It assigns to the uninitialised *p3 instead.

Comment: @cliffordheath I don't see anybody claiming that the original post contained an assignment to `p3`, but whatever. I think the OP's question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

The assignment asks you to make "***`p3`*** equal to the address of the fourth element of `s1`", but you're assigning the address to ***`*p3`***, not to `p3`.

`*p3` is what `p3` points to. `p3` is the address.

Btw your `*p3 = &s1[3];` [shouldn't even compile](http://goo.gl/pl2kiJ). If it does, enable your compiler warnings and errors.

Comment: The original post has no assignment to p3.

Comment: @cliffordheath: The OP says "I'm using the code `*p3 = &s1[3];`"

Comment: "my apologies I was typing fast I was already using the code p3 = &s1[3];" - apparently `*p3` was a typo in the question, and this is not the problem.

Comment: @dreamlax: I stand by my claim. The original version has no assignment to p3.

Answer (score -1):

```
p3 = s1+3;
```

Because the elements are at s1+0, s1+1, s1+2, s1+3, ...

Note that this is exactly equivalent to saying:

```
p3 = &s1[3];
```

... and some people who are uncomfortable with pointer arithmetic might prefer that. Personally I prefer the first version I gave.