# C++ Pointer and String addressing

Tags: c++

If we declare:

```
int i; 
int *ptr1 = &i;
*ptr1=10;
cout << ptr1;
```

Here ptr1 will give the address.
But:

```
char *ptr2;
ptr2="Priyesh";
cout << ptr2;
```

Here it will give the content of the character pointer.
Why is there such a difference?

Comment: USE gdb mate, for quick learning

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cout << with char\* argument prints string, not pointer value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17813423/cout-with-char-argument-prints-string-not-pointer-value)

Answer (score 5):

`operator <<` is overloaded specially for `char` pointers - the assumption is that if you try to print a `char` pointer, you actually want to print the string it points to.

If you want to print it the same way as any other pointer, cast it to `void*` first:

```
char *ptr2;
ptr2="Priyesh";
cout << static_cast<void*>(ptr2);
```

(or `cout << (void*)ptr2;`)

Comment: What's your mean by operator << is overloaded specially for char pointers?

Comment: Do you know what operator overloading is?  If so, then the explanation is clear.

Comment: I don't know operator overloading. Please explain a bit and give some link from where i can gain more knowledge.

Comment: @user3514850 Imagine it was a `print` function instead of `<<`... then there would be separate `print(const char*)` and `print(const void*)` functions. And if you did `print(p)` it would call the first one if `p` was a pointer to `char`, and the second one if it was any other kind of pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Because there's an [`operator<<` overload](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) that specifically takes a `const char*` argument to print it as a string.