# Why does std::cout of a dereferenced pointer to pointer cause -fsanitize=address to complain?

Tags: c++

```
char t = 'a';
char * p1 = &t;
char** p2 = &p1;
std::cout << p2 << " " << *p2 << " " << **p2 << '\n';
```

I am using clang and -fsanitize=address which complains about memory access overflowing a variable and terminates my program, however when I step through with gdb I can see that yes everything is defined and it should print two addresses followed by 'a'.

If I remove the middle "*p2" it runs fine, ie it is the printing of a half-dereferenced pointer to a pointer causing me issues.

Comment: Ok thanks I did not know that!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cout << with char\* argument prints string, not pointer value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17813423/cout-with-char-argument-prints-string-not-pointer-value)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::cout` assumes all `char*` point to null terminated character strings. Cast it to `void*` if you want the address.