# Converting int value to char pointer difference in C and C++

Tags: c++, c, pointers, casting

I wrote the following code to convert int value to char pointer and this works in C.

```
int i = 54;
char *ii;
ii = &i;
printf("%d\n", *ii);
```

The output is:

```
54
```

While when I write the same in C++, it doesn't work.

```
int i = 54;
char *ii;
ii =  (char *)&i;
cout<<*ii;
```

The output is:

```
6
```

Can someone please explain why this happens and how shall I get it working in C++.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looking through an [ASCII table](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/ascii) could be very helpful.

Comment: No, it's a bit different. In the question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17813423/cout-with-char-argument-prints-string-not-pointer-value  the user isn't able to print the address of the pointer, whereas I am not getting the correct value that the int holds. its quite different

Comment: The duplicate is not a perfect duplicate, but the basic problem and solution is the same: Printing a `char` in C++ prints a `char`, i.e. the character the encoded value represents.

Comment: Also note that you dodged *one* bullet by not having a [big-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Big-endian) system.

Comment: @ShubhamYadav - you're just getting lucky (or unlucky, depending on viewpoint).  Evaluating `*ii`  (in order to print it) gives undefined behaviour, in both C and C++ samples.    There is no requirement that the value printed by what you assigned.    The only difference is that a C++ compiler has to be forced to allow the initialisation of a`ii` (i.e. using an explicit type conversion), but a C compiler does not.    The net result is that there is no guarantee about what value your code prints, in either language.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of that question. The behaviour in the first part is like: `reinterpret_cast<int&>(*reinterpret_cast<char*>(&i))` (Which is legal, as `char*` is the object representation, and if it explicitly casted would be required to print `54`), and the second is just `*reinterpret_cast<char*>(&i)` (Which in this case the first byte is `(char) 54`, which as ASCII is `'6'`. On platforms with the opposite endianness, it would have printed the nul byte `'\x00'`)

Comment: @Peter A `char *` is allowed to alias other types for the purpose of accessing the representation of the pointed-to object.  The result is implementation defined, not undefined.

Comment: You are trying to trick the compiler. Ask it to do something you want the right way, and you'll get the result you want/expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different isn't the same. Try this:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int i = '6';
    char *ii = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&i);
    std::printf("%c\n", *ii);
    std::printf("%d\n", *ii);
    std::cout << *ii << '\n';
    std::cout << (int)*ii << '\n';
}
```

Initializing `i` to `'6'` is just a clarification.

In the calls to `printf`, the `char` value that `*ii` points to is promoted to `int` in the function call. Types smaller than `int` get promoted when they're arguments to the variable part of a function that takes a variable parameter list (such as `printf`).

The first `printf` statement prints the value of `*ii` as a character value; you'll get "6". The second prints it as an integer value; you'll get whatever value represents the character `'6'` (in ASCII that's 54, which is probably what you'll see).

The first insertion into `std::cout` inserts the `char` value; stream inserters are overloaded for integral types, so you get the inserter that takes an argument of type `char`, and it displays the character that the value represents, just like the first `printf` call.

The second insertion into `std::cout` inserts the integer value of `*ii`, just like the second call to `printf`.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `printf` like this:

```
printf("%d\n", *ii);
```

The `%d` format specifier means that the given `int` argument will be printed as an `int`.  Even though what you pass is a `char`, because `printf` is a variadic function it is **promoted** to an `int`, so it matches the format specifier.

When you output using `cout`:

```
cout<<*ii;
```

The `<<` operator has an overload for a `char`.  Since the right side has type `char`, that's the overload that is used.  That particular instance of `<<` prints the argument as a `char`.  Since the ASCII code 54 corresponds to the character `'6'`, that's what gets printed.

You'll get the opposite results if you use `%c` in the `printf` format, and if you cast `*ii` to `int` in the `cout` call.