# Confusion over char* array elements access

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am learning `c++` and encountered this:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){

const char *a[] = {"ge","hy"};
cout<<a<<" "<<&a[1]<<endl;
cout<<a[0]<<" "<<a[1];
return 0;
}
```

The output is :

```
0x7fff54e71830 0x7fff54e71838
ge hy
```

I tried to understand the code.

Here is my understanding:

`a` is an `array` of character pointers which means that each element of the array is a `char` pointer.

Now, since every element is a pointer then it should store the address of "ge" and "hy" respectively.

```
         -----------------------------------
 a  =    | 0x7fff54e71830 | 0x7fff54e71838 |
         -----------------------------------
```

Now when I write `a[0]` and `a[1]` then why does it print the `ge hy` and not the memory address of them because the array `a` stores their address and not their actual value.

I am sure that I'm going wrong somewhere because the output is not as expected. Kindly, correct me here.

Comment: "Ignoring the warnings". Nope, go back there and see what's happening..Hold your horses Rahul.. Understand that, and then proceed..

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17813423/cout-with-char-argument-prints-string-not-pointer-value/17813845) can help

Comment: @gsamaras I read it somewhere that `"abc"` is `const char a[]`. Isn't it right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard library provides an overloaded `operator<<(std::ostream&, const char*)` for printing C-style strings that prints the string pointed to rather than the value of the pointer itself.  That overload is a better match than the `operator<<(std::ostream&, void*)` overload that prints the address stored in a pointer.

If you want to print the value of the pointer, add a cast to `void*`:

```
std::cout << static_cast<void*>(a[0]) << ' ' << static_cast<void*>(a[1]) << '\n';
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/872c08abf45d0e2b)

Comment: Is this also the case with `char*`? Can I know how the `operator<<` is overloaded for different types in c++ without searching on Internet?

Comment: Also, for char c[] = {'a','b','c'}; then std::cout << c << '\n'; also prints abcand not the address of array `c`. Why is this printing abc and not the pointer value?

Comment: The `const char*` overload is a better match than the `void*` overload for `char*` since it only requires a const-conversion, as opposed to a type conversion.  Similarly, it's a better match for `char[N]` since it requires only one type conversion and one const-conversion (`char[N]` -> `char*` -> `const char*`) while a conversion to `void*` requires two type conversions (`char[N]` -> `char*` -> `void*`)