# How to retrieve the addresses of particular variables?

Tags: c++, memory-address

I got some code- I want to see how the particular variables are placed onto stack.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int fun(char b, long c, char d){
short p,q,r;
int y;
/***return &b,&c,&d,&p,&q,&r,&y;***/ - this one was for purpose of what should be returned, it is not valid code}

int main(){
fun('a',123,'b');
return 0;
}
```

Expected result would be addresses of particular variables, that's why I used operand &.
But still, I don't know where to place it in my code correctly, i.e. MAIN function.

REMARK: function does literally NOTHING, it is just an exercise for computer architecture course purpose.

Comment: Why not print them?

Comment: note that you pass the parameters by value, so once you mangaged to print addresses in `fun` it will be the adresses of the local variables, not of those in `main`

Comment: You can't return more than one thing at a time.

Comment: I know how the RETURN works @HolyBlackCat, it it commented for the purpose.

Comment: `return &b,&c,&d,&p,&q,&r,&y;` evaluates the addresses of 6 things and then discards them, with only the 7th impacting the result. I don't think there is an implicit conversion from `int*` to `int`, so `fun` is also ill-formed

Comment: Ok, my question is then-> how to call the FUN in MAIN function? To have addresses

Comment: You could aggregate aggregate all of the stuff you need to return into a structure and then return the structure.

Comment: @Marta It sounds like you are asking how to return many different objects from a single function. Is this correct?

Comment: your question is still unclear. You seem to know how to get the addresses, this is done by using the `&` operator. but what now? Do you want to keep main as is and `fun` is supposed to print the address of passed parameters to screen? Or do you maybe want `fun` to get the addresses and return them to `main` so you can print them in `main`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to capture the addresses within `fun` to see where they are on the stack (or whereever they are in memory), AND you want to return all those addresses to `main`, you can use this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

map<const char*, void*> fun(char b, long c, char d) {
  short p, q, r;
  int y;
  return {
    { "b", &b },
    { "c", &c },
    { "d", &d },
    { "p", &p },
    { "q", &q },
    { "r", &r },
    { "y", &y },
    { "b", &b }
  };
}

int main() {
  auto results = fun ('a', 123, 'b');
  for (auto p: results) {
    printf("%s is at %p\n", p.first, p.second);
  }
}
```

For me it displayed

```
b is at 0x7ffdec704a24
c is at 0x7ffdec704a18
d is at 0x7ffdec704a20
p is at 0x7ffdec704a36
q is at 0x7ffdec704a38
r is at 0x7ffdec704a3a
y is at 0x7ffdec704a3c
```

Remember that as others have pointed out, *you cannot use these addresses* in `main`! It would be much better, IMHO, to just do the `printf` invocations within `fun` itself. But no worries! Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Yes, in the case of `chars`, when you make these `char*`s and use `<<`, C++ will print them as...wait for it... C strings! :) Cheers.

Comment: Yes! Thank you! ☺️

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int fun(char b, long c, char d){
short p,q,r;
int y;
cout<<(void*)&b<<endl<<&c<<endl<<(void*)&d<<endl;
cout<<&p<<endl<<&q<<endl<<&r<<endl<<&y<<endl;}


int main()
{
fun('a',123,'b');
return 0;}
```

Ok, I got it now. This is the solution.

Comment: I still dont understand what the problem was, but at least you got a solution ;)

Comment: Not really; your has no MAIN-> this one I was looking for + (void*) to have letter address.

Comment: @AvinKavish when printing `char*` you have to cast to `void*` or similar to see the address, maybe that was the problem in the first place...

Comment: cool, never knew that. Never really printed addresses before.

Comment: note that you are printing the address of `b` not the address where the `'a'` from `main` is stored, the latter is possible but would require to modify how you pass the parameters

Comment: So this is pretty much a duplicate of [cout << with char* argument prints string, not pointer value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17813423/cout-with-char-argument-prints-string-not-pointer-value)