# Confused about pointers and their addresses

Tags: c++, pointers

I have created some pointer in code but the results are not what I expected.

Here is the simple code:

```
int main(int argc, char const* argv[])
{
    int myInt = 23;
    int* ptr = &myInt;

    char* buffer = new char[8];
    memset(buffer, 0, 8);

    char** ptr2 = &buffer;

    std::cout << "ptr address is " << ptr << std::endl;
    std::cout << "buffer pointer is pointing to address " << buffer << std::endl;
    std::cout << "ptr2 pointer is pointing to address " << ptr2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Dereferencing ptr2 = " << *ptr2 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And here are the results of running the code:

> ptr address is 0x7ffde215a14c
>
> buffer pointer is pointing to address
>
> ptr2 pointer is pointing to address 0x7ffde215a150
>
> Dereferencing ptr2 =

I am wondering why the buffer pointer address does not show and why the dereferencing of `ptr2` also shows nothing and yet the pointer (`ptr2`) pointing to the buffer pointer is showing that address. None of this makes any sense to me.

Comment: `*ptr2` is interpreted as a nul-terminated C style string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cout << with char\* argument prints string, not pointer value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17813423/cout-with-char-argument-prints-string-not-pointer-value)

Answer (score 7):

The stream `<<` operator is [explicitly overloaded for all kinds of `char*`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) to print it as a *null-terminated string*. To print the pointer you need to cast it:

```
std::cout << "buffer pointer is pointing to address " << reinterpret_cast<void*>(buffer) << std::endl;
```

Comment: Why `reinterpret_cast`, isn't `static_cast` safer in that it preserves the pointer value?

Comment: OK, then why did it not print the string?

Comment: @Clan The string is interpreted as a *null-terminated* string, and remember that your string is filled with null characters. Think about what that means.

Comment: @AlexanderZhang I believe we can do it in certain cases. See 10th point in explanation section of https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast.

Comment: This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/573345/12160191 says `For casting to and from void*, static_cast should be preferred`.

Comment: @TrickorTreat Sorry I forgot you can do so for `void*`.