# char pointer doesn't increment?

Tags: c++, pointers

after `ptr++` pointer does not increment

```
  1 #include<iostream>
  2 
  3 int main() {
  4 
  5         char *ptr;
  6         char ch = 'A';
  7         ptr = &ch;
  8 
  9         std::cout << "pointer :" << &ptr << "\n";
 10         ptr++;
 11         std::cout << "pointer after ++ :" << &ptr << "\n";
 12         return 0;
 13 }
```

```
ikar$ g++ pointer_arth.cpp 
ikar$ ./a.out 
pointer :0x7ffeed9f19a0
pointer after ++ :0x7ffeed9f19a0
ikar$
```

Comment: You increment one thing but print another.

Comment: @Raymond I've used pointers in C and C++ for 25+ years. I think I know how they work. Thank you.

Comment: @JesperJuhl As the answer original had like the question, https://onlinegdb.com/SyXktWxTH As you will see using just `ptr` will not work. Now he has changed his answer to the correct response. The original answer had no code and said just change to ptr.

Comment: @Raymond, neither will `*ptr` because then you'll potentially be dereferencing memory that doesn't belong to your program

Comment: @ForceBru `int *a; int b = 0; a = &b;` You said just output `a` with no pointer, that would point to the memory address. But somehow you all think `*a` is wrong. Your original answer only told him to remove the reference, your first answer was wrong until it was changed.

Comment: @Raymond, yes, the first version of my answer was just as wrong as dereferencing the pointer. Indeed, your comment about testing before answering helped me understand and fix the issue with my answer. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're incrementing the pointer, but outputting *the address of the variable that holds the pointer itself* (`&ptr`). You should output just `ptr` (and format it accordingly - see edit below).

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
 char data;
 char *ptr = &data;

 std::cout << "pointer:" << (unsigned long long)ptr << std::endl;
 ptr++;
 std::cout << "pointer incremented: " << (unsigned long long)ptr << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
pointer:140732831185615
pointer incremented: 140732831185616
```

Yes, printing just `ptr` will output garbage, so I converted the pointer to an integer (since pointers are memory addresses anyway).

As suggested in the comments, you can cast the pointer to `void *` when printing, which gives nicer formatting:

```
pointer:0x7ffee5467acf
pointer incremented: 0x7ffee5467ad0
```

Note how `0x7ffee5467acf == 140732745022159 != 140732831185615` - you'll get different outputs on each run because the kernel will load the executable into different places in memory.

---

EDIT: yes, the first version of this answer, about simply outputting `ptr` with `std::cout << ptr`, was incorrect, because the `<<` operator is overloaded in such a way that it [treats pointers to `char` as C-strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17813423/cout-with-char-argument-prints-string-not-pointer-value). Thus, that version would access potentially invalid memory and output garbage.

But the concept remains the same. Pointers to `int`, for example, don't have this "problem" and are printed as hexadecimal numbers, even without casting them to `void *`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dYtBCoMwEEX3OcVgQWzFC8RYqDcJySiBOAlxXBXPnsYsC64@7/OeiXEwXtOa88OR8YdFUC7snFBvbyEcMWzaUfcU3wp6rPOKnGCCtuDOVkoTDgaloJlxCQklNBddUplqIFk/ivL0/X/zWRjTbXLm/AM). The output shows that pointers are still incremented correctly by `sizeof(int)`, which equals 4 on that machine.

Comment: Weird choice of formatting (why not cast to `void*` instead? then you get nice hex output _and_ you don't have to guess whether your integer type is large enough) but the rest of the answer is sound

Comment: Does this this code have undefined behavior simply because `ptr` doesn't point to any valid address after `ptr++`?

Comment: @Ay One-past-the-end should be okay. I realise it's not an array strictly. Does that matter? Hmm.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica, yeah, casting to `void*` should be better, I haven't thought about that. I just happen to know that `unsigned long long` can fit a pointer on my machine, so I used that

Comment: @Ay You make a good point though - we should mention in our answers that this sort of "treat pointers like numbers" arithmetic is not as simple as it looks and shouldn't be done in general

Comment: @Raymond There was no substantive change to this answer, least of all one that would affect the code's well-definedness.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica I know that the standard allows one-past-end for arrays, but not sure if is valid in this case.

Comment: @Ayxan http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.lval#3.3 http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.stc.dynamic.safety#2.3 http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add#4.2 Think you're right.

Answer (score 1):

Pointer is incremented successfully in your code.
You print the address of location which hold the pointer variable.
Actually, it is garbage after character -'A' if print 'ptr', you can understand and pointing to such un-handled memory location is not good.

Comment: Thanks for this, that was all I was trying to say. Nice write up.