# Why does the following piece of code return the value pointed at by the pointer and not the address of the pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, operator-overloading, constants, c-strings

I have the following two lines of code:

```
const char* skimfile = argv[3];
cout << "skimfile = " << skimfile << endl;
```

I know that the above two lines of code work, but I am not sure why. If we want to print out the value that the pointer is pointing to, should we not use `*skimfile`? How is it that the above code uses only `skimfile` to access the value pointed at by the pointer `skimfile`? Does having `const` in front of the declaration of the pointer make this situation different?

Thank you very much for your help! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to output the value of the pointer then write

```
cout << "skimfile = " << static_cast<void *>( skimfile ) << endl;
```

Otherwise the operator << for character pointers is overloaded such a way that it outputs a pointed string.

Without such an overloaded operator you had to write for example

```
const char *s = "Hello";

for ( const char *p = s; *p; ++p )
{
    std::cout << *p;
}
std::cout << '\n';
```

instead of just

```
std::cout << s << '\n';
```

Comment: So, this is just unique to pointers of type ```char```, in that the name of ```char``` pointer can be used to print out the value pointed to by the ```char``` pointer without having to used ```*```? I am trying to understand someone else's code.

Comment: Yes, because char behaves differently as compared to other datatypes like int. and c++ has already overloaded methods for char datatype so that you don't have to parse it

Comment: @Bassa If you have for example a declaration like const char *s = "Hello"; then using this pointer like std::cout << s << '\n'; will output the pointed string. If you will write std::cout << *s << '\n'; then the first character of the string literal will be outputted.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not due to `const`. This is exactly how it should work and here is why:

skimfile is a pointer (in this case it is a pointer to const char) - so *skimfile is the object being
pointed to by the pointer

so cout << *skimfile should only print the first character.

When you do - cout << skimfile - you are passing the pointer itself. And cin will print out the whole string. In other words it would do cout << *skimfile, then cout << *(skimfile+1), until it has stepped through the whole string.

If you want to print the address you have to cast it to some other type of pointer - casting
as a pointer to void is the method most people use.
cout << "skimfile = " << (void*)skimfile << endl;

Here is a more detailed answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17813845/11979793

Answer (score 1):

The std::ostream such as std::cout is just a binary function `operator<<`.

For most pointers, the fallback just prints its address.

But `char const*` is printed expecting a C-style string or C-style string literal.  `ostream& operator<<(ostream&, char const*);` prints the characters until a `'\0'` stops the loop.

You can simulate that behavior with some simple structs:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::ostream;

namespace {

struct Coord { int x; int y; };
struct Stuff { int x; int y; };

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Coord const& coord) {
    out << coord.x << ", " << coord.y;
    return out;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Coord const* p) {
    out << p->x << ", " << p->y;
    return out;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Stuff const& stuff) {
    out << stuff.x << ", " << stuff.y;
    return out;
}

} // anon

int main() {
    auto coord = Coord{10, 20};
    auto stuff = Stuff{30, 40};
    auto pcoord = &coord;
    auto pstuff = &stuff;

    cout << "Coord: " << coord << "\n";
    cout << "PCoord: " << pcoord << "\n";
    cout << "Stuff: " << stuff << "\n";
    cout << "PStuff: " << pstuff << "\n";
}
```

Which has the output:

```
Coord: 10, 20
PCoord: 10, 20
Stuff: 30, 40
PStuff: 0x7ffeeaa06a88
```

Answer (score 0):

All the point here is that you are going to print the `char*` variable.

As you may know, in your code `skimfile` is pointed to the first character of a string of characters. So when you are going to print it, it will continue reading from memory until it gets `NULL` value, therefore, it will print all the string characters instead of its address.