# Pointer to array of pointers to array of char

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am currently studying C++ using Accelerated C++ by Koenig and i have a few troubles with the pointer to the initial array of pointers. It says in the book that the following code

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // if there are arguments, write them
    if (argc > 1) {
       int i; // declare i outside the for because we need it after the loop finishes
    for (i = 1; i < argc-1; ++i)
       // write all but the last entry and a space
      cout << argv[i] << " ";
     // argv[i] is a char*
      cout << argv[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

when ran with "Hello, world" arguments will produce Hello World but if `argv` is a pointer to an array of pointers then shouldn't `argv[i]` be a pointer to an array of `char` which output is a memory address instead of the array itself ?

Comment: Your understanding of pointer types is correct, but `char*` is a bit special, as it is almost always treated as a string. If this were some other kind of pointer, you would be right to expect the address to be printed out.

Comment: Possibly relevant question: [cout << with char* argument prints string, not pointer value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17813423/cout-with-char-argument-prints-string-not-pointer-value)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `char*` is a "C-string" -- it's how strings are represented in the C language. `std::cout` knows how to print `char*` because the `<<` operator is overloaded with the implementation.

C++ also has the `std::string` type, which is another way to represent strings.

Answer (score 0):

`char** argv` is the same as `char* argv[]`

a variable referencing an array in c++ is just a pointer to it's first element.

argv basicly is an array of c-strings which are arrays of chars.

argc tells you the amount of c-strings argv points to.

you do not need to know how long the c-strings (char[]) are because they are null terminated. It's just going to read the string char by char starting at that initial memory adress until it reaches the null terminator.

Comment: To be more precise, it is the same only when it appear as a function parameter, because array parameters decay to pointers. In general, `char**` and `char*[]` are different types.