# Why there is no output from `cout` but it is ok for `printf`

Tags: c++, c++11

To clear illustrate the problem, here is a minimal code. Why there is no output for my line `cout << z << endl;`? I am running it on Mac OS, compiler is `Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29) Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.3.0`

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main() {
  int x = 15;
  int *y = &x;
  unsigned char *z = (unsigned char *)&x;
  cout << y << endl; //this line works OK
  cout << z << endl; //no output of this line
  printf("%x", z); // this line works OK
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because, apparently, with your compiler using `<<` to output a pointer to an unsigned char does not print the pointer's value. The same thing happens as with a pointer to a plain char.

Comment: Check the different `operator<<` implementations, both the free ones and the ones implemented as member functions of `std::ostream`. BTW: Your code invokes UB by using the result of that C-style, brute-force cast. Don't use them unless you really know you need them.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I don't think it's UB per se. `unsigned char` is exempt from strict aliasing.

Comment: Hmmm, that may actually be true, @HolyBlackCat.

Comment: It seems that casting it into void will work. `cout << (void*)z << endl; `

Comment: Still, stop using C-style casts unnecessarily. That said, giving a pointer to `printf()` when the format string expects an integer will give you further issues. Most compilers can actually warn you of this, provided you enable warnings.

Comment: I was working a customized casting method which requires a byte by byte translating. It seems that (unsigned char *) is the only way that I know to operate in byte level.

Comment: `operator<<(std::ostream &, const unsigned char *)` interprets the pointer as C string and prints the string not the address. Casting to `void *` is a solution but you should avoid C-style casts. Use `static_cast<void *>`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cout << with char\* argument prints string, not pointer value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17813423/cout-with-char-argument-prints-string-not-pointer-value)

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I think that explains the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`operator<<` does not have an overload for an `int*` pointer, so the expression `cout << y` ends up calling the `void*` overload, which prints the memory address that the pointer is pointing at. It doesn't try to access the data being pointed at.  Same with `printf("%x", z)`.

`operator<<` does have an overload for an `unsigned char*` pointer, which treats the pointer as pointing to a null-terminated string, same as the `char*` overload does.  But `z` is not a pointer to a null-terminated string, so your code has *undefined* behavior when trying to print `z` this way.  To print the address that `z` is pointing at, you need an explicit typecast to `void*`, eg:

`cout << static_cast<void*>(z)`

That being said, the reason your code doesn't just fail outright is because the numeric value 15 (hex 0x0F) as an `int` happens to contain several `0x00` bytes in it (3 of them, if `int` is 4 bytes in size, as it is on most platforms).  Depending on endian, the `int` will be laid out in memory as either `0F 00 00 00` or `00 00 00 0F`. So, trying to print `z` as a null-terminated string will encounter one of those `0x00` bytes and interpret it as a null terminator. If the `0x0F` byte is encountered first, it will simply be interpreted as an ASCII control character that has no visual representation. Either way, you won't see anything being printed to the console.