# Why address of char behaves different than address of an int?

Tags: c++, pointers

Consider this small snippet

```
int x = 5;
std::cout << &x;
```

This prints some random hexadecimal number I.e. "0x62fe1c".

```
char x = 'a';
std::cout << &x;
```

While this version prints "a╨▬φ". I don't know what that is.

Comment: To reliably print a pointer, cast it to `void*`. Always.

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17813423/cout-with-char-argument-prints-string-not-pointer-value), it will bring up some clarity

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: or a `const void*` to keep everyone happy.