# Why does printing the location of a character output the character itself?

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ (coming from C), and I found some strange behavior that I didn't expect. 
 The symbol `&` gets you the location of a variable. This code

```
int a = 2;
std::cout << &a << "\n";
```

will output something like `0x7fffc010cb44` which makes sense, since this is where `a` is stored.

But if the variable is a character:

```
char b = 'x';
std::cout << &b << "\n";
```

The output here is simply

```
x
```

What's more bizarre, is that if I add some completely unrelated variables to the program, and I output only the location of the first one

```
char b = 'x';
char c = 'y';
char e = 'z';
std::cout << &b << "\n";
```

The program outputs all of them!

```
xyz
```

This clearly has something to do with memory allocation, since the other variables have nothing to do with `b`, but I have no idea why this happens. 
 So my question is - why does `std::cout << &b << "\n";` print the character stored in `b` instead of the memory location of `b`?

Comment: `&b` is a `char *` and `cout` treats them as strings. [cout << with char\* argument prints string, not pointer value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17813423)

Comment: Try this: `std::cout << static_cast<void*>(&b) << "\n";`