# Char array vs Int array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have the following problem:

```
int a[2][2]={{1,2},{3,4}};
cout<<a[1]; //the output is 0x29ff18 , which is an address
--------------------------------------------------------------------
char b[][6]={"hello","there","now"};
cout<<b[1]; //the output is there, which is value of b[1]
```

I am wondering why b[1] will not give an address like a[1]...

thanks!

Comment: `a[1]` and `b[1]` are arrays, not addressess.  But that's not related to your apparent issue.

Comment: I don't know why the outcome would be different

Comment: The expression `b[1]` is implicitly converted to `char*`, the stream overload for `char*` prints a string, if you want the address you'll need to cast: `std::cout << static_cast<void*>(b[1]);`. It prints the address in the case of `a` because there's no better overload for `int*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic difference between in a character array and an integer array is the terminating null character : `\0`
If you declare your character array like this :
`char b[] = {'h','i'};`
Then your `cout` statement fails to identify what to do, and will give strange output. But as soon as you do :

```
char b[] = {'h','i','\0'};
```

or

```
char b[] = "hi";
```

Your `cout` works fine. This is because in first, you are explicitly adding a null character at the end, and in the second, it gets added automatically by the compiler.

And for the array, and array declared as `a[]` or `a[][]`, the compiler stores the address of the first element of the array in variable `a`, so you get the address of the first element in case of an non-character array.
Refer to this link for more info : 
[What is the difference between int and char arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8271965/what-is-the-difference-between-int-and-char-arrays)

Comment: thanks! that means if I define char a[2]={'a','b'}, that is not correct? I should use a[3]={'a','b','\0'} instead??

Comment: @JackyLau Yes! Use the latter method, or simply a[3] = "ab"

Answer (score -1):

The type of v determines what cout << v prints.

One case you have int array, other case you have char array.  Cout by definition prints a char array different than int array.  Just the way it is.  As bjorne.